# Strange behaviour when using CSS gradients on text (Safari)

Tags: css, safari, paragraph, webflow

Hi guys I'm having this [strange behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9bQU.jpg) on Safari (version 13.0.5 on macOS Mojave) when using css gradients.

The paragraph looks perfect [on Chrome and Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ghlR.jpg). This is the code I'm using:

```
.highlight1 {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #FFFFFF 5%, #EE8344 91%);
               -webkit-background-clip: text;
               -webkit-text-stroke: 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
   color: #232323;}
```

The strangest thing is that just one word is disappearing from the paragraph. Any tips on how to solve this?

This is the live website: https://portfolio-84e6dc.webflow.io/

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to inspect it. The word "brewer" exist and doesn't disappear but it isn't on the same line of `span` so styles don't apply to it. when I tried decreasing font size the effect showed.

I suggest separating the word brewer in a different span and adjust styles in `highlight1` and a `NEW_CLASSNAME` to have a similar effect. But pay attention to the effect will happen according to screen different sizes using Safari

```
<p class="herotext">
    I spent some time in the 
    <span class="highlight1">world's largest </span>
    <span class="NEW_CLASSNAME">brewer</span> and the 
    <span class="highlight2">first brazilian unicorn</span> and now I design for companies 
    and startups.
</p>
```

Comment: Ouw gosh... so simple and I didn't think about! It worked DohaHelmy thank you so much.